# Finding a supremum of a two variable function

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Consider the function

$$f(x,y)=g_{1}(x,y)=-\frac{1}{y}\frac{\left( \ln \frac{x}{a}\right) ^{p}\left( \ln
\frac{b}{y}\right) ^{p}}{\left( \ln \frac{b}{a}\right) ^{p}},  1\leqslant a\leqslant x\leqslant y\leqslant b,\text{ }a\neq b$$
and $$f(x,y)=g_{2}(x,y)=g_{1}(x,y)+\frac{1}{y}\left( \ln \frac{x}{y}\right) ^{p}, 1\leqslant a\leqslant y\leqslant x\leqslant b,\text{ }a\neq b.$$
where $0<p\leqslant 1.$ 
 Find $\underset{x,y\in \lbrack a,b]}{\sup }\left\vert f(x,y)\right\vert.$